# My app crashes with the not responding but does not show any error in log cat....?

Tags: android

All i got to see is this. and nothing else. And also the other events in the log cat are not shown and the log below keeps on repeating..as you can observe the pattern below as well.Please help...!!!

```
   04-28 09:27:59.539 1099-1099/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Creating TransactionService
   04-28 09:27:59.619 1099-1099/? E/Mms/TransactionService: ====>TransactionService1 onStartCommand(), case 2
    04-28 09:27:59.749 1099-1099/? V/Mms/TransactionService: onStart: #1
    networkAvailable=false
    DatanetworkAvailable=false
    04-28 09:27:59.769 1099-1099/? V/Mms/TransactionService: onStart: cursor.count=0
onStart: no pending messages. Stopping service.
 04-28 09:27:59.789 1099-1099/? V/Mms/TransactionService: stopSelfIfIdle: STOP!
  stopSelfIfIdle: unRegisterForConnectionStateChanges
 04-28 09:27:59.969 1099-1099/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Destroying TransactionService
 04-28 09:27:59.979 1099-1133/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Handling incoming message: { what=100 when=0 } = EVENT_QUIT
 04-28 09:28:15.989 1579-1579/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Creating TransactionService
 04-28 09:28:16.009 1579-1579/? E/Mms/TransactionService: ====>TransactionService1 onStartCommand(), case 2
 04-28 09:28:16.009 1579-1579/? V/Mms/TransactionService: onStart: #1
    networkAvailable=false
    DatanetworkAvailable=false
   04-28 09:28:16.019 1579-1579/? V/Mms/TransactionService: onStart: cursor.count=0
   onStart: no pending messages. Stopping service.
  04-28 09:28:16.029 1579-1579/? V/Mms/TransactionService: stopSelfIfIdle: STOP!
  stopSelfIfIdle: unRegisterForConnectionStateChanges
 04-28 09:28:16.069 1579-1579/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Destroying TransactionService
  04-28 09:28:16.069 1579-1606/? V/Mms/TransactionService: Handling incoming message: { what=100 when=0 } = EVENT_QUIT
```

Comment: it seems you're running some services which are blocking main UI thread, consider using background services such as asynctask and intent services. share your code so we can have better idea of what's going on.

Comment: thanks for review. ya i was caused due to the background service of another app and the display was repeated because of the filter set...!!!